# Configuration files in install4j application

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I'm developing a install4j application for Windows. The application has a configuration directory that needs to be available for each user.  I have already tried to copy the config directory to ${installer:sys.programDataDir}, but the user can't edit the configuration files in Windows 7 from the application. So I want to make a copy of the configuration directory in the user home folder for each user separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install4j cannot enumerate all users for you, this is generally a difficult problem because users are not always local and you might end up with a huge number of potential users.

I would recommend to create the configuration files the first time a user starts your application. You can add a custom installer application that contains a "Copy file or directories" action that can be invoked from your own code. Select the custom installer application on the Installer->Screens & Actions tab, then activate the "Launcher integration" tab on the right side. The integration wizard will give you a code snippet.